# MongoDB query to remove a key of an Object in my database

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express

So, basically I'm trying to make an API Restful (just for studies purposes) with:

> NodeJS, Express and MongoDB

I already have my database set up, but I need to delete a `Key` from an `Object`.

If I send a request GET in my messages endpoint, this will return:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5f9b1e0186a911001714dd3c",
        "texto": "será se vai ?"
    },
    {
        "_id": "604fd3859b2fd50017027472",
        "texto": "salve rapaziada esse aqui é o texto que eu to colocando"
    },
    {
        "_id": "604fd4389b2fd50017027474",
        "texto": "Mensagem editada aAa",
        "mensagem": ""
    }
]
```

*The text is in PT-BR*

The key `mensagem` was a misstake, but now I wanna know how to resolve.

So, I wanna delete `mensagem` key, the third object.

I'm using NoSqlBooster, but if someone use Mongo Compass, I need to know too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/)

[update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update)

`unset` will remove the key from the collection and passing `true` at the end of the `update` method is a flag set to `update multiple records.

```
db.collectionName.update({}, { $unset: { mensagem:1 } }, { multi: true });
```

Comment: Ok, it works, but this command line will remove all the keys with this name in my collection ?

Comment: Yes, it will remove all the keys.